# SaveFlush not giving the changed object details + Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am looking to send the new order object `orderEdited`  after `saveAndFlush` to the subsequent function call `updateDashBoardCounts`, but it does not seem to be working ie. `orderEdited` still contains the old order object details. Any way in which this can be done???

```
..
order.setDate(blah);
...
Order orderEdited = null;
orderEdited = orderRepository.saveAndFlush(order);
customerSearchService.updateDashBoardCounts(orderEdited);
```

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening with you. What repository you've extended your interface with?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike save(), the saveAndFlush() method flushes the data immediately during the execution. This method belongs to the JpaRepository interface of Spring Data JPA. Here's how we use it:

```
employeeRepository.saveAndFlush(new User(232L, "Foo"));
```

Normally, we use this method when our business logic needs to read the saved changes at a later point during the same transaction but before the commit.

For instance, imagine a scenario where we have to execute a stored procedure that expects a property of the entity, which we're going to save. In this case, the save() method won't work since the changes are not in sync with the DB and the stored procedure doesn't know about the changes.

It might be not reloading your changes because you are getting the details in a **new Object** where to inject the same changes the reference needs to stay same. So instead of taking a new object I would suggest you collect the return type in same object you've edited and you will see the changes in your DB

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "old order object details"? `saveAndFlush` will flush the state of the object that you passed to the database, but the order object will not be changed. If your database does something to rows through e.g. triggers, you can reload the object after clearing it from the persistence context with `EntityManager.clear` or `EntityManager.detach`.